# Multi-node multi-datacenter CASSANDRA

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to setup a multi-node multi-datacenter cluster in Cassandra 3.11

For data-center 1 I have Cassandra running on 3 nodes(eg. 10.90.22.11, 10.90.22.12 and 10.90.22.13) and for data-center 2 I have Cassandra running on 2 nodes(eg. 10.90.22.21 and 10.90.22.22).

The ring is up but they are working separately. To make them work together I update the endpoint_snitch to be GossipingPropertyFileSnitch and also the dc and rac in cassandra-rackdc.properties to be DC1 and DC2 for respective nodes following the steps mentioned in [this link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/ddac/doc/datastax_enterprise/production/DDACmultiDCperWorkloadType.html).

After these changes when I restart Cassandra, the status of Cassandra is running however when I check for the ring with nodetool status I receive a error:

```
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199'
ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: First of all, did you set cassandra-rackdc.properties? Second - did you clean out the data on all the nodes? Switching snitches isn't a simple task, and the state is stored in the data, so you need to clean out the data, commitlog and hints dirs. You also need to restart the service of course.

Answer (score 0):

This error you posted indicates that `nodetool` couldn't connect to JMX that is supposed to be listening on port `7199`:

```
Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199'
```

Verify that Cassandra is running and check that the process is bound to various ports including `7199`, `9042` and `7000`. You can try running one of these commands:

```
$ netstat -tnlp
$ sudo lsof -nPi | grep LISTEN | grep java
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should try nodetool command with host/IP what you have put in your cassandra.yaml. Also, you should check your port 7199 or custom port if you set  is open/allow from firewall.

nodetool -h hostname/ip status.

you can mention username.password if you enabled. please refer below link for more details and understanding:-
http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/nodetool/status.html